# What are the difference between "corporate" and incorporate"?

Tags: word-choice

Today, I read a paragraph

> The political economy approach is not inconsistent with normative
> theory, since normative theory should **incorporate** the political
> behavior that invariably accompanies policy choice and implementation.
> In economics, moral hazard or adverse selection are taken into account
> in the design of a regulatory policy.

I noticed the word "incorporate". I remember and search and see that incorporate and corporate has the similar meaning when they are noun. I am wondering what is the difference between these two words, or they only different because "incorporate" but "corporate" can be a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary or a brief search online would answer your question.

Both words derive from **corpus**, the Latin for body, which gives rise to numerous English words, particularly those regarding companies.

**incorporate** is a verb that can be used as an adjective;

**corporate** is an adjective that can be used as a noun.

You will find numerous illustrations of their use online.